Problematic install of babel-scottish
Here are two failed attempts to install the downloaded (by MiKTeX) files for babel-scottish. It seems to revolve around the missing file hilatex-dev.fmt presumably needed for XeLaTeX. The internet seems strangely quiet if you attempt a search for this file, so I am at a loss to solve the update formats problem. There doesn't seem to be the necessary update button in the MikTeX Console to rebuild the language database. What should I try next?
C:\Users\hsmye>miktex --enable-installer formats build
security risk: running with elevated privileges
Building format 'latex-dev' with engine 'pdftex'...
Building format 'amstex' with engine 'pdftex'...
Building format 'lualatex-dev' with engine 'luahbtex'...
Building format 'pdfcslatex' with engine 'pdftex'...
Building format 'pdfcsplain' with engine 'pdftex'...
Building format 'dviluatex' with engine 'luatex'...
Building format 'csplain' with engine 'pdftex'...
Building format 'cslatex' with engine 'pdftex'...
Building format 'mltex' with engine 'pdftex'...
Building format 'bagpipe' with engine 'pdftex'...
Building format 'lualatex' with engine 'luahbtex'...
Building format 'bplain' with engine 'pdftex'...
Building format 'optex' with engine 'luatex'...
Building format 'bagpipex' with engine 'pdftex'...
Building format 'dvilualatex-dev' with engine 'luatex'...
Building format 'dvilualatex' with engine 'luatex'...
Building format 'etex' with engine 'pdftex'...
Building format 'lollipop' with engine 'pdftex'...
Building format 'hilatex' with engine 'hitex'...
Building format 'hilatex-dev' with engine 'hitex'...

Sorry, but: Windows API error 2: The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\Users\hsmye>

initexmf --dump
2024-04-25 11:43:37,451-0600 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the private (per-user) MiKTeX setup
2024-04-25 11:43:37,456-0600 INFO  initexmf - running: miktex --enable-installer formats build
2024-04-25 11:43:37,456-0600 INFO  initexmf.core - start process: miktex --enable-installer formats build
2024-04-25 11:45:32,696-0600 INFO  initexmf - this is MiKTeX Configuration Utility 5.5 (MiKTeX 24.3.31)
2024-04-25 11:45:32,696-0600 INFO  initexmf - this process (21316) started by cmd in directory C:\Users\hsmye with command line: initexmf --help
2024-04-25 11:45:32,696-0600 INFO  initexmf - Operating on the private (per-user) MiKTeX setup
2024-04-25 11:46:28,488-0600 ERROR initexmf - sub-process error output has been saved to 'C:\Users\hsmye\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\miktex_2024-04-25-114628.out'
2024-04-25 11:46:28,488-0600 FATAL initexmf - Windows API error 2: The system cannot find the file specified.
2024-04-25 11:46:28,489-0600 FATAL initexmf - Info: existing="C:\Users\hsmye\AppData\Local\Temp\mik45435\hilatex-dev.fmt", path="C:\Users\hsmye\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex/data/le/hitex\hilatex-dev.fmt"
2024-04-25 11:46:28,489-0600 FATAL initexmf - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\File\win\winFile.cpp
2024-04-25 11:46:28,489-0600 FATAL initexmf - Line: 376
2024-04-25 11:46:28,490-0600 INFO  initexmf - this process (16556) finishes with exit code 1

Sorry about the length; this is as close to an MWE as I can get.
BTW, have you ever seen a Windows install that buchered a user name? Notice the user name in the log files…
Almost forgot, here is the warning in a run with XeLaTeX
[{
    "resource": "/C:/Users/hsmye/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/babel-scottish/scottishgaelic.ldf",
    "owner": "LaTeX",
    "severity": 4,
    "message": "Package babel: No hyphenation patterns were preloaded for\n(babel)\tthe language 'Scottish Gaelic' into the format.\n(babel)\tPlease, configure your TeX system to add them and\n(babel)\trebuild the format. Now I will use the patterns\n(babel)\tpreloaded for \\language=0 instead.",
    "source": "LaTeX",
    "startLineNumber": 41,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 41,
    "endColumn": 65536
}]

Sorry about the formatting of the message, but this is what a 'copy' returns.
New information, this is from my current run
(C:\Users\hsmye\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/babel-scottish\scottish.ldf (C:\Users\hsmye\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/babel-scottish\scottishgaelic.ldf

Package babel Warning: No hyphenation patterns were preloaded for
(babel)                the language 'Scottish Gaelic' into the format.
(babel)                Please, configure your TeX system to add them and
(babel)                rebuild the format. Now I will use the patterns
(babel)                preloaded for \language=0 instead on input line 41.

It clearly knows about the necessary files but can't seem to get to them. I've filed a bug report in GitHub with MikTeX.

hilatex(-dev) is unrelated to xetex it is for the new hitex engine

Thanks for the update, that makes this the first point of error, then @DavidCarlisle

it looks like an error in the setup for format building but I don't know how that's configured in miktex so someone else will have to answer

the format building fails for me too but don't see a reason. The hilatex format works. You should report that. In the mean time you can exclude the format in the miktex console in the settings.

Half my project is in Scottish Gaelic, so I pretty much need this to work. Thanks, though, @UlrikeFischer!

I just tried to exclude the offending file only to find out that it won't let you save the information, and if you try to delete it instead, it tells you that you can't delete built-in formats.

hm, yes I can change the status of a normal format but not of a -dev format. Report it.

Yes ma'am! @UlrikeFischer

I don't believe (but I'm not certain) that there are any hyphenation patterns for Scottish Gaelic. There are for other Celtic languages, but not this one. Unless the name is aliased somewhere. (This is TeX Live, but I'm assuming the same will be true on MikTeX - it's just Babel.)

Three files argue otherwise, and they are now on the language list. I suppose they could be placeholders, but that seems a stretch. This is in the latest MiKTeX, it was missing earlier, even though Babel had it. I use TeX Live under Linux, but not this project. It is interesting to hear the current difference though. Thanks @cfr

You mean you have hyphenation patterns for Scottish Gaelic? Not just language files? Huh. I suppose they might not meet TeX Live's criteria, which are stricter than MikTeX.

@hsmyers babel provides language definition files for scottishgaelic, but it doesn't provide hyphenation patterns. Welsh, for example, uses patterns in a file hyph-cy.tex but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent for Scottish Gaelic. The three files you're referring to are babel files. They say what the correct hyphenation patterns should be called, but they don't provide them.

I'm fine with that, @cfr; I just despise warnings that are hard to get rid of, no matter how useless they may be.

They are not useless in this case. They are just unrelated to the update problem. (They are not useless, I think, even if you, personally, have no way to get rid of them. Until TeX gets hyphenation patterns for a language, half its typographic ability is nullified. Unless you only type very short words, the results will be poor. Worse, TeX will apply US English hyphenation to Scottish Gaelic. So it isn't just that it can't find good breaks. (How much affect it has will depend on whether any of the rules can actually be applied, which may not be much.))

My experience so far is that no hyphenation is taken unless I tell it where with - I'd like to say that as this is a beginner's text, there are no long words, but this is Scottish Gaelic, and there is no such thing as only short words! You are right, @cfr, warnings are necessary, but it is irritating when you can't fix the problem you've been warned about!

@hsmyers Agreed. At least the US rules aren't having much effect ;). Do you know if there are hyphenation rules somewhere? That is, not for TeX, but if somebody somewhere has compiled a suitable set for some other reason?

I do not @cfr, but then I haven't looked yet ;)
